# Configuring minipage in latex 2

Tags: graphics, boxes, minipage

[image]I want to use minipage in latex and I want the input as below

I used the cfg template of answer but it is not same as picture. I hope that someone can help. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm,exscale, commath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

 \usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{center}
\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont SOCIALIST REPUBLIC OF VIETNAM\\ {\bf 
\underline{Independence-Freedom-Happiness}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{0.3cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.87\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\bf \fontsize{17pt}{16pt}\selectfont \flushleft Curriculum vitae}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\flushright{\rule{2.5cm}{3cm}}
\end{minipage}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below code may help you:

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm,exscale, commath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

 \usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\hbox to \textwidth{
\begin{minipage}{20pc}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont SOCIALIST REPUBLIC OF VIETNAM\\ {\bf 
\underline{Independence-Freedom-Happiness}}\\[3pc]
{\bf \fontsize{17pt}{16pt}\selectfont \flushleft Curriculum vitae}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\flushright{\rule{2.5cm}{3cm}}
\end{minipage}
}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: this has not fixed most of the issues in the original. notably `\flushleft` and `\flushright` are doing nothing as the group ends before they take effect, and it further adds the issue that `\hbox` should not be used in latex documents, and that you have added a space at either end of the line.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I want have the text ''Figure (3 x 4)'' same as picture

Comment: @Mary Do you mean that right side black box should replace with a picture? Please correct if my assumption is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

your image is not very clear (does't show position of your title and image). in assume, that title (mini pages) not spill out of text border):

[image]

- `15pt` is not defined font size, consequently default font size of `10pt` is considered
- `\bf` is not latex command. instead of it you should use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}
- for defining font size you can use `\large`, `\Large`, `huge` ... version of used fonts
- `flushleft` is surplus
- ...

image of your document above is obtained with the following *mwe*:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd, amsthm, exscale, commath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[showframe,
            left=3cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}           % <--- added, use instead of minipages
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}     % <--- added, for inserting of images
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % <--- added, for positioning image in table

\usepackage{lipsum}             % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\noindent%
{\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{25mm}
                             >{\centering\let\\\newline}X
                             p{25mm}
                             }
    &
    \Large
    SOCIALIST REPUBLIC OF VIETNAM

    \underline{\textbf{Independence-Freedom-Happiness}}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \large
    \textbf{Curriculum vitae}
    &   \includegraphics[width=25mm, height=30mm, valign=t]{mypicture}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
}

\lipsum
  \end{document}
```

Comment: @Mary , are this means that my answer gives what you looking for?  if yes, you can vote it (by clicking up-pen at the top left side of answer or even accept it :-).